# fseek Process finished with exit code 11

Tags: c

I don't know why, but when I do `./a.out`, it gives me that error:

`Process finished with exit code 11`

If I comment the `fseek` and the `ftell`, it doesn't give me an error? 
why ? 
I did a logical error?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main (){


        FILE *file_pointer;
        int size=0;


        if((file_pointer = fopen("file.txt","rb")) == NULL)
        {
            printf("Ok Man File was charge in the pointer");
            fseek(file_pointer, 0, SEEK_END);
            size=ftell(file_pointer);

            printf("%d",size);
            rewind(file_pointer);
            fclose(file_pointer);
        } else
            printf("File Not Found");




    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just tested whether the file open *failed*, and if it fails you go on to try and use it.  The return value of `NULL` indicates an error, and you cannot use the handle.

So, you should change your `==` to `!=`:

```
if((file_pointer = fopen("file.txt","rb")) != NULL)
{
    ...
}
```

Or slightly more readable style (in my opinion):

```
file_pointer = fopen("file.txt","rb");
if(file_pointer)
{
    ...
}
```

By the way, there is no need to `rewind` before you `fclose`.

Comment: its not a video you are returning to the store, you dont have to rewind to be polite

Comment: Thanks you, have a nice day!